# How to setup jsp-config at JavaConfig

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, web.xml

in web.xml

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <description> </description>
        <display-name>JSPConfiguration</display-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>EUC-KR</page-encoding>  
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

in JavaConfig

```
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {
        //  ??
        }
}
```

How to setup jsp-config at JavaConfig?

Comment: You have access to it with `servletContext.getJspConfigDescriptor().getJspPropertyGroups();` returning a `Collection<JspPropertyGroupDescriptor>` which has an `add(JspPropertyGroupDescriptor)` method. `JspPropertyGroupDescriptor` is an interface which you have to implement. You're probably better off having a partial web.xml and partial java configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code should work:

```
    JspConfigDescriptor j = new JspConfigDescriptor()
    {

        @Override
        public Collection<TaglibDescriptor> getTaglibs()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<JspPropertyGroupDescriptor> getJspPropertyGroups()
        {
            Collection<JspPropertyGroupDescriptor> c = new ArrayList<JspPropertyGroupDescriptor>();
            JspPropertyGroupDescriptorImpl pgDescriptor = new JspPropertyGroupDescriptorImpl();
            pgDescriptor.setIsXml(Boolean.TRUE.toString());
            pgDescriptor.getUrlPattern().add("/js/generated/*");
            pgDescriptor.setElIgnored(Boolean.FALSE.toString());
            pgDescriptor.setPageEncoding("UTF-8");
            c.add(pgDescriptor);
            return null;
        }
    };
    servletContext.setJspConfigDescriptor(j);
```

But last statement will be available since Tomcat 8

Comment: Can you extend your example a bit? the ServletContext does not seem to have the setJspConfigDescriptor method, at least not in the tomcat-embed-core-8.0.5.jar

Comment: does not have setJspConfigDescriptor in tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar@javax.servlet.ServletContext or  javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar@javax.servlet.ServletContext ...

Comment: @maxb To write JSP settings, one need to access the JSP engine implementation, or continue using web.xml. In the code snippet in this answer `servletContext` is `org.apache.catalina.Context`, not `javax.servlet.ServletContext`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59344649/156973

Answer (score 0):

> You have access to it with
>
> ```
> servletContext.getJspConfigDescriptor().getJspPropertyGroups();
> ```
>
> returning a `Collection<JspPropertyGroupDescriptor>` which has an
>   `add(JspPropertyGroupDescriptor)` method. `JspPropertyGroupDescriptor` is
>   an interface which you have to implement. You're probably better off
>   having a partial `web.xml` and partial java configuration.
>
> [Sotirios Delimanolis Apr 24 at 16:07](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196696/how-to-setup-jsp-config-at-javaconfig#comment23157800_16196696)