# Programmatic Servlet 3.0 JSP jsp-property-group configuration

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlet-3.0

I am able to create servlets and filters in my [ServletContainerInitializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html), but is it possible to translate this last remaining piece of an old `web.xml` into Servlet 3.0 programmatic configuration?

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
        <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Comment: no one's gonna answer? how did you deal with it?

Comment: I am using this with 3.1 - no problems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servlet 3.x specifies only the *reading* interface for JSP settings.

To *write* JSP settings, one need to access the JSP engine implementation, or continue using `web.xml`. The latter is not a big issue since `web.xml` can safely coexist with `ServletContainerInitializer`. So advise is to keep `web.xml`.

It is however an issue with Spring Boot, which ignores `web.xml`.

With **Spring Boot 2** with an embedded **Tomcat** it can be achieved using [`TomcatContextCustomizer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/embedded/tomcat/TomcatContextCustomizer.html):

```
@Component
public class JspConfig implements TomcatContextCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(Context context) {
        JspPropertyGroup pg = new JspPropertyGroup();
        pg.addUrlPattern("/*");
        pg.setPageEncoding("UTF-8");
        pg.setTrimWhitespace("true");
        ArrayList<JspPropertyGroupDescriptor> pgs = new ArrayList<>();
        pgs.add(new JspPropertyGroupDescriptorImpl(pg));
        context.setJspConfigDescriptor(new JspConfigDescriptorImpl(pgs, new ArrayList<TaglibDescriptor>()));
    }
}
```